# How can i draw bounding box and not use the normalized coordinate in tensorflow object-detection api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

How can I draw bounding box and not use the normalized coordinate in [tensorflow object-detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)? in object_detection_tutorial.ipynb , I noticed that default coordinate is in normalize coordinate and form of boxes is [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax] and how to convert them to [image_length*xmin, image_width*ymin,image_length*xmax,image_width*ymax]?
I try to use

```
        boxes[0]=boxes[0]*200
        boxes[1]=boxes[1]*100
        boxes[2]=boxes[2]*200
        boxes[3]=boxes[3]*100
```

but error happens:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-efcec9615ee3> in <module>()
     30                   feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
     31                 boxes[0]=boxes[0]*200
---> 32                 boxes[1]=boxes[1]*100
     33                 boxes[2]=boxes[2]*200
     34                 boxes[3]=boxes[3]*100
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: Check the dims of boxes variable.  At index zero is the bboxes for image one.  At index 1 is the Nx4 matrix of bboxes for the second nd image, and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

if you look at research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py the boxes[0] is ymin not xmin when you multiply these coordinates with 100 or 200 make sure it is still in the image boundary (im_width, im_height). 
 You can try boxes[0]* 100, boxes[1]* -200, boxes[2]* -100, boxes[3]* 200, this is similar to this code.

```
ymin = boxes[0]*100
xmin = boxes[1]*-200
ymax = boxes[2]*-100
xmax = boxes[3]*200

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
im_width, im_height = image.size
(left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                              ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)

draw.line([(left, top), (left, bottom), (right, bottom),
               (right, top), (left, top)], width=thickness, fill=color)
```